# Uploading video from another server to Facebook

Tags: facebook, upload

We can upload videos facebook with  "video.upload" but problem is more specific.

video source in example.com and i can get video link like example.com/example.mp4

if i download this video to my server; i can upload the video to facebook  but it will really slow.

can i upload video from example.com to facebook.com directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but instead of uploading the bytes of the data directly from the other server, you can just link to the url on the other server  :)